# Using field names containing the "@" (@timestamp) in elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a feeling that my question must have a trivial answer but several 
hours of googling and searching python tutorials and I am still stuck.

My Field names often contain the "@" character (i.e @timestamp)
and the "@" is used by python for decorator functions.

How do you reference these field names in elasticsearch-dsl?
(I am using python 3.6.2)

```
resp = s.execute()

for hit in resp:
    print(hit.response_code)
    print(hit.@timestamp)
```

Of course I tried escaping and quoting.

Answer (score 1):

you can always use `hit['@timestamp']` or `getattr(hit, '@timestamp')`

Comment: Thx a lot, I new I was missing something trivial. Regards, Peter